# How can i decode JWT using Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, keycloak

I am using Keycloak with Spring-Boot in my application. My browser client request keycloak to generate JWT and then sends this JWT to my ZUUL server which validates JWT using keycloak-spring adapter and then i have written a pre-filter to decodes JWT payload and extract username.
I am using com.auth0.java-jwt library to decode JWT like in below snippet

```
 DecodedJWT dJWT=JWT.decode(header);
 String username=dJWT.getClaim("preferred_username").asString();
```

I was wondering if there is anyway i can do this without using external library. I want to use keycloak library to decode JWT explicitly. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason why you're doing it at zuul? I guess it is some request auditing you want to do? Because I've got zuul only to reverse-proxy to the service I'm interesting on, then the service is spring-security + keycloak adapter powered. The spring keycloak adapter makes this stuff itself.

Comment: I am using zuul as API Gateway, where in i do authentication/authorization and some request filtering and if success then pass on the request to downstream service.

Comment: IMHO, zuul shouldn't bother about auth/auth. Specially about authorization, since from my point of view is highly coupled with business logic, which belongs to your downstream services. Anyway, for this your case you could just configure the keycloak spring adapter in the zuul service (as you're using spring itself) and don't bother about decoding the JWT yourself.

Comment: I just figured that out and pulled the details from SecurityContextHolder itself.

Answer (score 13):

You have to include keycloak's core library into your dependencies.
Gradle: `compileOnly 'org.keycloak:keycloak-core:3.4.2.Final'`

Then use the `org.keycloak.TokenVerifier` to parse the token.
Example:

```
try
{
  // deprecated: AccessToken token = RSATokenVerifier.create(tokenString).getToken();
  AccessToken token = TokenVerifier.create(tokenString, AccessToken.class).getToken();
  System.out.printf("iss = %s%n", token.getIssuer());
  System.out.printf("sub = %s%n", token.getSubject());
  System.out.printf("typ = %s%n", token.getType());
}
catch (VerificationException e)
{
  // some error handling
}
```

You can also activate various verifications on the RSATokenVerifier and in particular the signature validation by setting the public key:

`RSATokenVerifier.create(tokenString).checkActive(true).publicKey(key).verify().getToken()`

Comment: 'e.printStackTrace();' is a bad idea

Comment: RSATokenVerifier is deprecated, you should use TokenVerifier, and the code is: `AccessToken token = TokenVerifier.create(tokenString, AccessToken.class).getToken();`

Answer (score 2):

As i am using keycloak to authenticate jwt, it decodes jwt and puts details into SecurityContextHolder and I just pulled the details from there it self. here is the code.

```
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {
            KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> kp = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>) authentication.getPrincipal();
            // retrieving username here
            String username = kp.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getPreferredUsername();
            }
      }
```

this solved it for me.